# Show vuetify stepper label on mobile

Tags: vuetify.js

I was trying to figure out how to show the labels of `v-stepper` on mobile devices since they are hidden by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to scss or css overrides:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
  .v-stepper:not(.v-stepper--vertical) .v-stepper__label {
    display: flex !important;
  }
}
```